# Trying to call place and run a javascript function into an already built html page

Tags: javascript, html

I couldnt find the answer to my problem, so I hope someone does know the answer.

I am trying to make a support-chat, for which I am trying to load in a chat window in the 'admin-area'. This works all fine, but the function that needs to collect the incoming messages does not run. It works when I call it in the console, and it shows up in the html, but it does not run by itself. The function is defined in the .js file that is being included beforehand. This is the html that gets placed into the page:

```
<script>setInterval(function(){getClientMessages();}, 1000);</script>
```

I know I could solve the problem with a redirect, and place the function in the page by start up, but the idea is to open and close a conversation in the same page.

Comment: Does the console report any errors when opening the page?

Comment: By "placed into the page", do you mean that the page's XML has that `script` element, or is it being inserted after the fact?

Comment: before i load the chat, is does not have the script tags in this place. It does have one that checks for incoming chatrequests.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run script simply by creating a `<script>` tag and inserting it via innerHTML. The contents script tag would then have to be executed via `eval()`.

Alternatively you could define an external source and insert the script tag more directly like google does for analytics:

```
(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: A point to note for onlookers. Using eval is heavily discouraged. It has inherent security risks.  This is probably one reason why google does it differently, I guess.

Comment: I just realized it's probably easier to bypass the problem and  just combine the function that checks for new chat-requests with the function that collects the incomming messages. Would not need to load it in than...

Comment: @PimpTrizkit excellent addendum. `Eval()` is often maligned, typically to prevent XSS attacks. If you control all the script and aren't using any user-input in your `eval()` it is generally safe, if not fast. It remains in the language because it is a useful tool when used properly.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes. Its possible to use it "Safely"... hmm.. maybe my quotes need quotes on that one....